# converting std::string to upper case without modifying source

Tags: c++11, toupper

I'm acquainted with the usage of std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::toupper), which can change the string in data to all uppercase.  I am wondering, however, if there is a clean solution that can get the all-uppercase version of a string without modifying the source?   The workaround of making a copy of the source and then calling std::transform on the copy, and then returning the copy seems a bit like a kludge, and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient and elegant solution.

I am looking for a pure C++11 solution... without dependency on any even widely available C++ libraries such as boost.

Comment: "making a copy of the source and then calling std::transform on the copy, and then returning the copy " Is as efficient as you would get if you're not changing the source.

Comment: do you mean that somehow the string is turned uppercase at compilation time, while being lowercase in the source?

Comment: `std::string udata; std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(udata), ::toupper);`. Nothing says the transformation must happen in place.

Comment: If you post that comment as an answer, I will flag it as the correct answer, and the question can be marked as answered.  I never knew about std::back_inserter.  Most cool.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Igor's comment above, the solution is to use an std::back_inserter on the destination....  `std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(dest), ::toupper);`